# Java Remove duplicated from multiple Array

Tags: java, arrays

i have a question on how to remove duplicate for multiple Array. Basically what i want to achieve is to compare from 4 Array and if the contain of Array are exactly the same then i want do not want to print out.
The example of contains for each as below shown:

```
ArrayStudentName   ArrayAge     ArrayGender  ArrayCourse
A                     9             Boy           IT
B                    10             Boy           IT
B                     9             Boy           IT
A                     9             Boy           IT
A                     9             Girl          IT
```

Is that the only way to remove the duplicate with using 4 times of for loops or do i have to merge 4 arrays into 1 array and then use HashMap to remove duplicate before u print out the result.
The result i need is:

```
ArrayStudentName       ArrayAge     ArrayGender  ArrayCourse
    A                     9             Boy           IT
    B                    10             Boy           IT
    B                     9             Boy           IT
    A                     9             Girl          IT
```

Comment: Define a POJO for the attributes and overwrite equals method and store them in the Set structure.

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge
previously i was using 4 for loop to remove the duplicate, but it seems complicated and messy. so far i am trying to use HashMap to do it, but i am trying to get is there any easier way to do it.

Comment: Or loop over the first array and search for duplicates, if you found a duplicate in the first array, check if the elements in the other array at the two duplicate indices match as well - if they do in all arrays then you really have found a duplicate and can remove it.

Comment: Curious....why are you using 4 Arrays to begin with? Why not just use a 2 dimensional Array to hold all the data?  dataArray[n][4]

Comment: @DevilsHnd A single array with an actual object that contains these values would be far simpler that a two-dimensional array.

Comment: That's true @Mark it would be. I guess the point I was trying to make is...why have 4 Arrays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be brave and take the OOP route. Make a `class` called `Student` and fold all the values into that class. Then you just need to put them in a `Set` which, by definition, does not allow duplicates.

You do, however, have to implement `equals` and `hashcode` (or `Comparable` if you choose not to use a `HashSet`).

```
enum Gender {

    Boy, Girl, Other;
}

enum Course {

    IT, CS;
}

class Student {

    final String name;
    final int age;
    final Gender gender;
    Course course;

    public Student(String name, int age, Gender gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + "\t" + age + "\t" + gender + "\t" + course + "\n";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Student other = (Student) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.age != other.age) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.gender != other.gender) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}

public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(
            new Student("A", 9, Gender.Boy),
            new Student("B", 10, Gender.Boy),
            new Student("B", 9, Gender.Boy),
            new Student("A", 9, Gender.Boy),
            new Student("A", 9, Gender.Girl)
    );
    // Fold it into a Set to eliminate duplicates.
    Set all = new HashSet();
    all.addAll(students);
    // Pull back out into a List.
    System.out.println("Students:\n" + all);
}
```

Comment: This answer is better than my answer. This should be accepted !

Comment: I have to agree with @OldCurmudgeon his suggestion is the best practice and will keep your code clean and understandable,

Comment: hi, may i know how to put my multiple array's value into the List so that i can eliminate duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Student` Class.

```
public class Student {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private String gender;
  private String course;

  // Implement Getters and Setters here.


  // Then Override the equals method like this:
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Student student = (Student) obj;
    if ( this.name.equals( student.getName() ) &&
         this.age == student.getAge() &&
         this.gender.equals( student.getGender() ) &&
         this.course.equals( student.getCourse() )
       ) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can create an array of `Student` objects and compare them using `equlas` method.

Answer (score 0):

easy way: use a Set (to get unique entries), an keep order: LinkedHashSet

Then Read each line in a List< String >

and keep them in a  LinkedHashSet< List< String> >

This gives something like that (you must loop and scan your datas of course !)

```
Set<List<String>> sls=new LinkedHashSet<List<String>>();

sls.add(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"A","9","Boy","IT"}));
sls.add(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"B","10","Boy","IT"}));
sls.add(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"B","9","Boy","IT"}));
sls.add(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"A","9","Boy","IT"}));
sls.add(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"A","9","Girl","IT"}));

System.out.println(sls);
```